# Form input field not showing, javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "textman.php",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#textbaz').append(data);
      $('#textbaz').append("<input id='textbox' type='text' placeholder='Type it man, your on the clock!'");
    }
  })
})
```

The above is my javascript code. The first command(Appending data to textbaz) works perfectly and the data is printed. Problem is, the second line breaks. 
For some reason it just doesnt print out, i checked the chrome dev tools and it isnt there at all. I am very confused and any and every help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It's because you forgot the `>` from the end.

Comment: you didn't close the input tag

Comment: It's because you forgot `/>` from the end

Comment: Wow, didnt know forgetting /> is something you can get negative rating about..

Comment: @aayushdagra the reason you got a negative vote, IMO is that this problem could have easily been resolved by doing some research first - validating your HTML for a start ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#textbaz').append("<input id='textbox' type='text' placeholder='Type it man, your on the clock!' />");
```

You need to close the input tag.

Comment: Thanks! Will mark correct ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

You missed closing `/>` of your input element:

```
<input id='textbox' type='text' placeholder='Type it man, your on the clock!' />
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- ^ here
```